# Likeliness of being denied a Data scientist position because only knowing Python or R?

Tags: resume

Many Data Scientist/Analyst job ads write requirements for the position are "Python and/or R".

I have 5+ experience in one of the languages and curious how often applicants get turned down an interview/job because they "only" know one of the languages?

Comment: Impossible to know.

Comment: Well of course there is no data but maybe people with experience can answer if they denied someone because he would not fit in the team because only knowing one lanuage, they were looking for someone to look into some code that was written in Python etc

Comment: it would not tell you anything. Each job is different and has different requirements. Some teams would require you to be expert in one or the other or both, some will not. You're better off simply asking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question:

> ... requirements for the position are Python and/ **or** R. I have 5+ experience in one of the languages

In your question title:

> ... only knowing Python **or** R

The job advertisement specifies that you are only required to know one of them. You state that you have over 5 years' experience in using one of them.

You are qualified for the job, so there's no harm in applying. It might be that there is someone else who applies who knows both languages, so they are **more** qualified for the job than you are, but you are qualified. You might end up being the most qualified person who applies/ come across best at interview time, so they might hire you even if there is someone who is **more** qualified on paper.

I have never worked in Data Science/ Data Analysis, so can't speak directly to that industry, but as someone who studied computer science, and worked in software development for a number of years, I interviewed for, and accepted offers for several jobs despite not actually having any experience of the main programming language they were looking for.

If you have a good grounding in programming/ scripting with a language that is similar to the one they're looking for, you should be able to sell your ability to pick up the particular language/ skill they're looking for quickly, as you have experience of something similar.

Obviously, only state this if you are confident in your ability to do this/ can prove that you have done this in a previous role (don't lie).

While I was self-employed, I successfully interviewed with a client who were looking for a Python developer, despite having never used Python previously (I think I'd had one lecture on it during the whole 4 years of my degree- so I was just aware of it as a language). But, I was aware of useful resources I could use to help me 'learn on the job' (sites like StackOverflow, [w3Schools tutorials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf8ceAkOXmAhUOGsAKHRxyA-UQFjAAegQIBxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fpython%2F&usg=AOvVaw3DDMaeRvoPZxdqsRK3yoWF), etc), and, already having a good knowledge of a number of programming/ scripting languages, I was confident in my ability to pick up & use another language quickly- it's just a case of googling the right syntax, keywords, etc to use.